# Como carregar Lightbox2 ao entrar na página

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Estou tentando a algum tempo resolver uma situação que tenho, preciso que ao entrar no site uma propaganda seja exibida e para isso estou tentando usar o `plugin` `Lightbox2` mas na documentação do próprio plugin não é indicado como fazer isso, fiz algumas pesquisas e até cheguei em algumas alternativas mas mesmo assim nada funcionou.

Consegui esse código no SO em inglês e fiz como recomendado:

```
// Automagically load Lightbox on Page Load - by Bramus! (http://www.bram.us/)
// Code modded from http://www.huddletogether.com/forum/comments.php?DiscussionID=1269&page=1#Item_0
function autoFireLightbox() {
    //Check if location.hash matches a lightbox-anchor. If so, trigger popup of image.
    setTimeout(function() {
            if (document.location.hash && $(document.location.hash.substr(1)).rel.indexOf('lightbox') != -1) {
                myLightbox.start($(document.location.hash.substr(1)));
            }
        },
        250
    );
}
Event.observe(window, 'load', autoFireLightbox, false);
```

Link da pergunta em inglês:
[Lightbox2 pageload trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688329/lightbox2-pageload-trigger)

No corpo da minha página tenho esse link:

```
<a href="imagens/promocao.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" id="myLightbox"></a>
```

Mas mesmo com as tentativas não obtive êxito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código que você tentou usar, mostrado na pergunta e copiado de uma questão do site gringo não me parece ser o que você precisa. O código apenas verifica se na URL da barra de endereço do navegador possui um `hash` específico para disparar uma função. O que você quer, na verdade, é mais simples, que é apenas disparar o link com o Lightbox2.

Isso é bem simples de se fazer:

Basta, após o carregamento do DOM, você disparar um `.click()` no link do Lightbox2 após um pequeno *delay* com `setTimeout`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $("#myLightbox").click();
   }, 500);
});
```

Veja que coloquei um atraso de `500 milissegundos` (ou meio segundo), já que a [documentação do plugin](https://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) não informa nenhum `callback` de quando o componente foi carregado (o que seria o ideal). Então você pode ajustar esse valor de `500` para mais ou para menos de acordo com o que achar melhor e que o tempo seja suficiente para que o plugin tenha sido carregado.

**Importante:**

O evento `$(document).ready(function(){...` necessita que o jQuery já tenha sido invocado na página, senão resultará em erro. Você pode substituir essa linha pelo código nativo do JavaScript `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){` se quiser ou for o caso.

Veja funcionando:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      $("#myLightbox").click();
   }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.1/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.1/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" id="myLightbox"></a>
Aguarde meio segundo...
```

Uma outra forma é usando `setInterval` até que a `div#lightboxOverlay` seja criada pelo plugin, indicando que ele já está pronto:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var tempo = setInterval(function(){
      if($("#lightboxOverlay").length){
         clearInterval(tempo);
         $("#myLightbox").click();
      }
   }, 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.1/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightbox2/2.11.1/js/lightbox.js"></script>
<a href="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="" id="myLightbox"></a>
```

Comment: Olá @Sam, muito obrigado pela respostas e exemplos, ficou muito bom.

Answer (score 3):

Até aonde sei `Event.observe(...);` é uma "função" do `prototype.js` (https://github.com/prototypejs/prototype/blob/5fddd3e/src/prototype/dom/event.js#L763, não confundir com [`<Object>.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)), logo se olhasse no console do navegador provavelmente iria ver muito bem evidente o erro:

> TypeError: Event.observe is not a function

Basta usar o que é NATIVO que não vai ter problemas:

```
window.addEventListener("load", autoFireLightbox);
```

Ou pode usar também o `DOMContentLoaded`, que só espera até o DOM estar pronto, assim sendo mais rapido que o `load`, pois não vai precisar esperar outros recursos:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", autoFireLightbox);
```

Claro que usando jQuery você pode usar o `$.ready()` (ou o equivalente `$()`), assim:

```
$(autoFireLightbox);
```